# Is it legal javascript (ECMAScript) for a function to reference its attributes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is it legal javascript (ECMAScript-5) for a function to reference its attributes?

```
var baz = function(callback) {
  return callback();
};

var foo = function() {
  return foo.bar;
}

foo.bar = 1;

foo(); // 1?

baz(foo);  // 1?
```

Edit: can you refer me to the part of the ECMA specification that declares this is legal?

Comment: `function(callback) = {`?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Folks often run into a problem with this when using objects, which are evaluated during initialization and don't exist while attempting to reference their properties. This is not a problem with functions, since the property isn't accessed until the function is invoked later.

For example:

```
let foo = {
  bar: 1,
  baz: foo.bar + 1
};
```

fails because the object has not been assigned to `foo` yet, so `foo.bar` is undefined.

With functions this is not a problem, since `foo` is a reference to the function and `bar` would not be accessed until the function is *invoked*:

```
function foo() {
  return foo.bar + 1;
}

foo.bar = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a function is an object, objects have properties and they may access their properties.

Remember that in JS functions are first class citizens, they can have their own properties. Also remember that property evaluation happens *when the function is called* and not when it is created so the property can be added later.

You can see this here:

```js
var foo = function() {
  return foo.bar;
}

foo.bar = 1;

alert(foo()); // 1?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nicer pattern, like this:

```
var baz = function() {
  var myVal = 0;
  return function() {
    //body
  }
}()
```

That way you have a sort of memo variable inside closure that will keep values for you

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects, so sure, they can have properties and access them. Just be aware that the body of a function has no magical access to those properties.

Note that code like this requires the body of the function to know its name:

```
function foo() {
   return foo.bar;
}
```

.. but you can take advantage of the `arguments` property to remove that redundancy/dependency:

```
function foo() {
  return arguments.callee.bar;
}
foo.bar = 1;
foo();  // 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, arguments.callee is deprecated and accessing it throws in strict mode.

Comment: i strongly recommend not using `calee` as it will not be supported in future versions of browsers and even now is slowly being depreciated

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. And an argument against putting properties on function objects directly, I'd say.